# How to increment by a fixed value for all elements in an input list using numpy?

Tags: numpy

I have the following python function and need to implement it using numpy arrays.
(1) It takes 3 parameters an input list, an increment value and a stop value.

```
def createlist(inputlist,incrementby,incrementtowards):
    Y = inputlist.copy()
    while max(Y) <= incrementtowards:
        Y = [i + incrementby for i in Y]
        for v in Y:
            if v <= incrementtowards:
                inputlist.append(v)
    return inputlist
```

Following are the expected outputs considering 2 inputs:

```
createlist([1,3,8],10,50)
```

which returns:

```
[1, 3, 8, 11, 13, 18, 21, 23, 28, 31, 33, 38, 41, 43, 48]
```

and

```
createlist([1,3,8,35],10,50)
```

which returns:

```
[1, 3, 8, 35, 11, 13, 18, 45, 21, 23, 28]
```

Essentially the following does something similar but the first parameter does not support a  **'list'/'array'**, is there any simple way to achieve this?

```
a = np.arange(1,50,10)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What should the output of `createlist([1,30,100], 10, 50)` be ?

Comment: [1, 30, 100] @psidom

Comment: That's inconsistent from your 2nd example. Why not `[ 1 30 11 40 21 31 41]` ?

Comment: Because the input list itself does not meet the condition for the while loop.

Comment: I would assume `arr + np.arange(0, 10, 50)[:,None]` and then filter the array by max values would be the numpy way.

Comment: I'm not sure what your lines do but if I pass an input list of [1,3,8] then it returns a list [2,4,9]

Comment: What I mean is this `np.array(inputlist) + np.arange(0, incrementby,incrementtowards)[:,None]`

Comment: Thanks for your patience Psidom, this does look like it does the trick however it returns a list of lists, but atleast this points me in some direction, I'll try and figure out how to return a single list with all elements. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Just one more thing Psidom, I had to interchange the incrementby and incrementtowards in the np.arrange() call. Thanks.